# Como faço produto de vetor por matriz e entre matrizes?

Tags: c

Não consigo pensar em um for que realiza essa multiplicação,pelo fato de que o numero de colunas da primeira matriz tem que ser igual ao numero de linhas da segunda matriz...

Comment: Procure um pouco da suas aulas de geometria analítica ou álgebra linear. Lá você fez esses cálculos. Tente simular na mão o que fizera no passado. Também verifique se sua estrutura de dados está adequada; matematicamente puma matriz tem duas dimensões valoradas e também tem seus valores internos, no corpo da matriz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Produto Matricial

Antes de fazer qualquer código é necessário saber como funciona o produto entre matrizes.

Considerando duas matrizes `A` e `B`, o produto matricial é feito multiplicando cada valor de uma linha de `A` por cada valor de uma coluna de `B`, e somando esses parciais todos. Este processo é assim aplicado a todas as linhas de `A` e colunas de `B`.

Veja uma ilustração deste processo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Considerando as matrizes da ilustração `A` com dimensão `4x2` e `B` `2x3`, a matriz resultante, a qual chamarei de `R`, terá o tamanho `4x3`. Aqui vê que `R` tem de ter a quantidade de linhas da primeira matriz e a quantidade de colunas da segunda matriz.

Nesta matriz `R` a primeira casa `R11` seria então definida por:

```
R11 = A11*B11 + A12*B21;
```

A segunda casa `R12`, que está realçada na figura a vermelho, seria calculada como:

```
R12 = A11*B12 + A12*B22;
```

E assim sucessivamente para as restantes casas.

### Cálculo em C

Agora que já sabemos como funciona o produto entre matrizes podemos passar à implementação. Indicou um `for` para a resolução do problema e na verdade serão necessários 3 para tal. Os 2 primeiros `for` percorrem cada célula da matriz resultante e o `3` percorre o A e B para fazer o calculo.

Implementação:

```
int A[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
int B[2][2] = {{2,0},{1,2}};
int R[2][2] = {0};

int i,j,k;

for(i=0; i<2; i++){
    for(j=0; j<2; j++){
        for(k=0; k<2; k++){
            R[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
        }
    }
}
```

[Veja o exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/m77NxO)

Nota: O produto entre vetor e matriz é a mesma coisa que o produto entre matriz e matriz, pois um vetor é um caso particular de uma matriz com apenas uma linha ou uma coluna.

Leitura recomendada:

- [Produto de Matrizes na Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Produto_de_matrizes)