# Multiplicação de matriz em Java

Tags: java, matriz

Preciso fazer com que duas matrizes se multipliquem, mas estou errando na hora de fazer a multiplicação.

```
    int ma[][] = new int [3][2];
    int mb[][] = new int [2][2];
    int mab[][] = new int [3][2];

    for (int i = 0; i < ma.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ma[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.println("Digite o elemento da linha " + (i + 1) + " e coluna " + (j + 1) + " da matriz 1");
            ma[i][j] = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mb.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mb[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.println("Digite o elemento da linha " + (i + 1) + " e coluna " + (j + 1) + " da matriz 2");
            mb[i][j] = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        }
    }

    mab[1][1] = (ma[1][1] * mb[1][1]) + (ma[1][2] * mb[2][1]);
    mab[1][2] = (ma[1][1] * mb[1][2]) + (ma[1][2] * mb[2][2]);
    mab[2][1] = (ma[2][1] * mb[1][1]) + (ma[2][2] * mb[1][2]);
    mab[2][2] = (ma[2][1] * mb[1][2]) + (ma[2][2] * mb[2][2]);
    mab[3][1] = (ma[3][1] * mb[1][1]) + (ma[3][2] * mb[2][1]);
    mab[3][2] = (ma[3][1] * mb[1][2]) + (ma[3][2] * mb[2][2]);

    System.out.println("Multipliacação das matrizes:");

    for (int i = 0; i < mab.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mab[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.println(mab[i][j] + "\t");
        }
    }
```

No netbeans, indica que da erro na linha 26, que é onde tem a primeira multiplicação, aparece essa mensagem:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
>       at multiplicacao.Multiplicacao.main(Multiplicacao.java:26)

Será que errei na operação? sou novo com java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ao criar um vetor você passa como parâmetro o tamanho dele `new int[tamanho]`.
Os índices do vetor começam do 0, conforme a [documentação da Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html). Você também pode ver nesse [link da caelum](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/um-pouco-de-arrays/#5-1-o-problema) sobre vetores.

Se você criar um vetor `int vetor = new int[2]` então ele possui as posições `vetor[0]` e `vetor[1]`.

No seu caso, quando você criou o a matriz `int mb[][] = new int [2][2];` não existe o índice `mb[X][2]` existem os índices de `mb[0][0]` até `mb[1][1]`

Você pode fazer o seguinte ajuste no código:

```
//Seu código
mab[1][1] = (ma[1][1] * mb[1][1]) + (ma[1][2] * mb[2][1]);
//Ajuste
mab[0][0] = (ma[0][0] * mb[0][0]) + (ma[0][1] * mb[1][0]);
```

Comment: Isso mesmo, valeu, muito obrigado

Answer (score 5):

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Significa que está a aceder a uma posição fora das posições validas do array.

No seu caso isso dá-se aqui:

```
mab[3][2] = (ma[3][1] * mb[1][2]) + (ma[3][2] * mb[2][2]);
```

Os indices de arrays em Java começam sempre em `0`, logo o `ma` que foi definido como:

```
int ma[][] = new int [3][2];
```

Tem posições validas para `[0 a 2][0 a 1]`.

No entanto a lógica que está a fazer deveria ser feita através de um laço/ciclo, para que possa ser dinâmica e adaptável a quaisquer dimensões.

Segue um exemplo de calculo com `for` e acertando outros pormenores que estavam menos bem:

```
Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in); //criar o Scanner apenas uma vez

int ma[][] = new int[3][2];
int mb[][] = new int[2][2];
int mab[][] = new int[3][2];

for (int i = 0; i < ma.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < ma[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.println("Digite o elemento da linha " + (i + 1) + " e coluna " + (j + 1) + " da matriz 1");
        ma[i][j] = teclado.nextInt(); //ler com base no Scanner criado
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < mb.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < mb[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.println("Digite o elemento da linha " + (i + 1) + " e coluna " + (j + 1) + " da matriz 2");
        mb[i][j] = teclado.nextInt(); //ler com base no Scanner criado
    }
}

//calculo da multiplicação das matrizes
for(int i=0; i<mab.length; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<mab[i].length; j++){
        for(int k=0; k<ma[i].length; k++){
            mab[i][j] += ma[i][k] * mb[k][j];
        }
    }
}
```

[Exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/BM1cpN)

[Leia também outra resposta que já dei sobre multiplicação de matrizes em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/246325/como-fa%C3%A7o-produto-de-vetor-por-matriz-e-entre-matrizes/246354#246354)